# How to maintain structure in gradle sourceset with more than one src directory

Tags: java, gradle

In my root project I have 3 directories. Let's call them A,B and C. All of those directories contains some directories with .java files. Those files are dependent on each other somehow. Now, when I run gradle build task, gradle creates rootDir/build/classes dir. But all of those .class files are mixed. I want to have classes/A/<some .class files>, classes/B/<some .class files> and classes/C/<some .class files>. Instead I got all of them under one classes/main. For now my sourceSets look like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {java {
                    srcDirs "A/src"
                    srcDirs "B/src"
                    srcDirs "C/src"
            }}}
```

I tried to create different structure like this:

```
sourceSets {
    A {java {srcDirs "A/src"}}
    B {...}
    C {...}}
```

Then, when I try to run this task:

```
task A(type:Jar) {
    from sourceSets.A.output.classesDirs
    from sourceSets.A.java.srcDirs
    include '**/*.class'
    archiveFileName = "A.jar"}
```

Obviously I got compilation error, since those classes cannot find methods from B and C.
Is there any way to resolve this, or I will be forced to change structure of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired class file separation based on the directories A, B, and C in your Gradle build, you can use different configurations for each source set and specify dependencies between them. This way, you can control the class file output for each directory and ensure that dependencies are correctly resolved during compilation.

Here's a step-by-step approach to set up your Gradle build:

1. Define source sets:
   Define separate source sets for directories A, B, and C.

   sourceSets {
   A {
   java.srcDirs = ['A/src']
   }
   B {
   java.srcDirs = ['B/src']
   }
   C {
   java.srcDirs = ['C/src']
   }
   }
2. Define dependencies:
   Specify dependencies between the source sets to ensure that classes from B and C are available to A, and classes from C are available to B.

   dependencies {
   AImplementation project(':B')
   BImplementation project(':C')
   }

Replace `AImplementation` and `BImplementation` with the appropriate configurations depending on your project structure.

3. Configure JAR tasks:
   Configure JAR tasks to include the specific class directories for each source set.

   task AJar(type: Jar) {
   from sourceSets.A.output
   archiveFileName = "A.jar"
   }

   task BJar(type: Jar) {
   from sourceSets.B.output
   archiveFileName = "B.jar"
   }

   task CJar(type: Jar) {
   from sourceSets.C.output
   archiveFileName = "C.jar"
   }

   jar.dependsOn AJar, BJar, CJar

In this setup, we've defined separate JAR tasks for each source set (A, B, C) and configured them to include the respective output directories. Additionally, we've set up dependencies between the source sets to ensure proper class file resolution during compilation.

You can then run `gradle AJar`, `gradle BJar`, or `gradle CJar` to generate the JAR files for each source set. Adjust the dependencies and configurations according to your specific project structure and requirements.